# How to use JMenuItems to display integers on seperate lines in a JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, append, jtextarea, jmenuitem

I'm using a JMenu (named Count)  with four JMenuItems (named Inc, Dec, Reset, Quit). When I click on any of the menuitems I want it to display the integer in the JTextArea. For example, everytime I click on Inc it should show the integers vertically listed starting from 0. The issue right now is that when I press the Dec menuitem its not taking the last number listed.

I tried to use the getText method but I keep getting a NumberFormatException and saying that the input string is a bunch of numbers e.g.:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

From what I can tell, I am aware that I need to be able to keep track of the last number in a way that all menuitems (aside from the quit menuitem) can access it and change it. I just have no idea how to do it.

Here is one of the ways that I've tried where it gives me the error I mentioned above.

```
//newLine = "\n";

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

      String ac = ae.getActionCommand();

         if(ac.equals("Inc")) {    

            jta.append(count + newLine);
            count++; 

         }
         else if(ac.equals("Dec")) {

            count = Integer.parseInt(jta.getText());
            countText = Integer.toString(count); 
            jta.append(countText + newLine);
            count--;

         }
         else if(ac.equals("Reset")) {

            jta.selectAll();
            jta.replaceSelection("0");   
            count = 0;

         }
         else if(ac.equals("Quit")) {

            System.exit(0);

         }

}
```

I was expecting

```
0
1
2
3
4
3
2
1
```

to be displayed in the TextArea when I click on Inc and Dec

But instead its just

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

and then I get a `NumberFormatException` saying that the input string is:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

If possible, I would like the input string to be just the last integer in the textarea.

I hope this makes sense. This is my first time making a post on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

When you get the text, it has returned "0 1 2 3 4" which cannot be parsed an integer, therefore the exception.
If you want to get the last integer in the text field, you need to retrieve the text and find the substring that represents the last integer. Look at the javadocs for String, especially the lastIndexOf(), split(), and substring() methods.

If you have placed each integer on a separate line, and have kept track of the last number entered in an instance variable "count", then you just need to call `jta.append( (count-1) + newLine);` without having to retrieve the text at all.

Note that your code does not save the last number entered - it saves (last+1)